# Best input type to record a time Duration in Html

Tags: html, reactjs

I'd like to create a field in my fitness app to record the duration of a users workout.

The input field in html has a time type, but it is set to record an actual time - 02:30 PM.

```
<input type='time'/>
```

I can't find an input field to record something like so 00:25:30...so if a user runs a 5k in 25 minutes and 30 seconds, they can record it like so?

Is there a best practice, or another html element that can handle this? If not I'll have to code up something in JS to handle input in that format.

Comment: have you tried `select` tags?

Comment: `<progress>` element will display a duration and current time. The mechanics of it actually functioning will have to be JavaScript. There are no magical elements that record or display time at intervals without JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try "step" attribute.

```js
document.getElementById("mytime").value = "19:36:24";
```

```html
<input id="mytime" type="time" step="1" />
```

This is one of the many applications of "step" attribute, you can set the step attribute to 1 and can get the time with precision of second.
This should solve your problem.

Comment: Just adding a note to this solution, although it works it's not super intuitive for the end user. Mostly for countries defining time with AM/PM.
These users will have an AM/PM selector on a field meant to define a duration wich is counter intuitive :/
The AM/PM indicator can be hidden via CSS but the selector will always show it there's no way to avoid that for now. A proposal thas been made to allow developpers to force a locale on the field so we could disable that but AFAIK it's not possible yet.